# Google Play Developer Console error: The version code of your APK is high and you risk not being able to update your APK

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I'm trying to update my app to the Google Play Store. I have the current version number of the app set to 2000000000 and would like to update it to 2000000001. Please don't ask my why there are such version numbers chosen.

[image]

I got this error message when I try to push the new version: "Upload failed
The version code of your APK is high and you risk not being able to update your APK.". The one thing I don't understand is that according to official google documentations the max version number is MAXINT, 2147483647, so I still have roughly 150 000 000 versions left. The other thing is, I managed to update other app with the same version numbering convention, the app is on the same dev account and I have no such error at all.

[image]

I checked all the numbers couple of times to be sure I'm not doing some stupid typo. I also already contacted Google support but maybe someone here have some kind of solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Google support responded to my requests. They changed the maximum available version code to **2000000000** and didn't update the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) at the time I was posting this question (right now it is still **MAXINT: 2147483647**). Quite an edge case here but maybe someone will find this useful.

Comment: Cross-posted the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38847981/4625829) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38866995/4625829) since it's the most viewed posts for max versionCode inquiries.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like there was an update 08/11/2016 (UTC) in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html). Not the old `MAX_INT` value or the 2000000000.

> Warning: The greatest value Google Play allows for `versionCode` is **2100000000**.

Comment: What happens after this value? Any way to reset it?

Comment: @GokhanArik You should contact Official Google Support thru email.

Answer (score 0):

My Unity app had a high version code (not sure where from), I added version 3 and version code 3 in the Unity app, and that shut Google Play :) There is a crafty version for build.gradle though [Unity 3D: What is the Android Bundle Version and Version Code and how do they relate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720229/unity-3d-what-is-the-android-bundle-version-and-version-code-and-how-do-they-re)